# Table as a page header

Tags: tables, header-footer, multirow, page

I started using Overleaf this year for my lab reports, and I am wondering if there is a way to use a table as a header. I have tried pasting Excel data into a table generator, but this hasn't worked for me.

[image: This is the header I have been trying to create]

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with code showing what you've tried and clarify what you mean by 'header'. Headers usually appear at the top of all pages which don't start with titles of chapters or the document title. Do you really want this on every page except the first/first of chapters?

Comment: Easiest would be to cdreate a savebox and use the savebox as the header.  You can create the savebox in the preamble and measure the total heigth (for \headheight).

Comment: As it is currently written, this is not a question related to Overleaf, but a general (La)TeX question.

Comment: you can use a `tabular` anywhere that you can use a letter so yes. (I would not use a table generator website, from what I have seen from examples posted here they generate terrible latex code). If you have problems show a small complete example and show the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[headheight=102pt, includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\headwidth}{|c|X|l|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{6}{*}{\includegraphics[width=0.15\headwidth]{example-image}} &
        \multirow{6}{*}{\parbox{\hsize}{\centering FACULTAD DE CIENCIAS FISICAS\\ Y FORMALES}} &
        Código & \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Versión & 01 \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Página & \thepage/\pageref{LastPage} \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & Sección ISO & 8.3 \\ \cline{3-4}
    & & {Fecha de} & \multirow{2}{*}{\quad/\quad/2024} \\[-0.5\baselineskip]
    & & {presentatión} & \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|p{0.5\headwidth}|}{Escuela Profesional de Ingeneria Mecánica, Mecánica Eléctrica y Mecatrónica} &
       \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Área: Laboratorio de Termofluidos}} \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{La impresión de este documento es una copia no controlada} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}%
}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]